# Regular expression to find words that begin and end with

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Good evening, (sorry for my English is not my native language) I'd like to find words in HTML text.
I don't get what I want and I ask for help. Sample text:

```html
<div class="text-slate-500 text-white text-5xl bg-white bg-slate-600 bg-red/5 ....."> </div>
```

I should like to find **only** the words that begin with **bg-** or **text-** and ends with **0**

This is the best result I've been able to get,
but what's missing to find final 0?

\b(bg-\w*)\b

https://regex101.com/r/Krh5JV/1

\b(text-\w*)\b

https://regex101.com/r/f6v8UL/1

Thanks for help!

I've tried several formulas found on the net, I've tried to look for other posts here but I couldn't get anything better.

/(bg.*00)/g

https://regexr.com/7p8fd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `\b(bg-[\w-]*0)\b`. `-` isn't covered by `\w` and thus your existing patterns would not match `bg-slate-600`, so we add it in as a possibility in a list with `[\w-]`. This is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]`. Then add `0` to the end of the capture group before the word boundary (`\b`) for the stipulation that it should match an ending `0`.

- [`\b(bg-[\w-]*0)\b` on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/myk9CF/1)
- [`\b(text-[\w-]*0)\b` on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9BOfbk/1)

Answer (score 1):

If seems that you want to find only classnames that start with either `bg-` or `text-` and ending on a zero.

You can make use of an alternation `|` combining both using a non capture group. To get the matches only, you don't need any capture groups.

```
\b(?:bg|text)-[\w-]*0\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPlnfi/1)

To get all the elements, you can make use of `querySelectorAll`

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = `<div class="text-slate-500 text-white text-5xl bg-white bg-slate-600 bg-red/5"> text-doNotMatchThis-500 </div>`;

const allElms = div.querySelectorAll('*');
const result = [];
const regex = /\b(?:bg|text)-[\w-]*0\b/;

allElms.forEach(element => {
  element.classList.forEach(clsName => {
    const m = clsName.match(regex);
    if (m) result.push(m[0])
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/(bg)+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+0/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should accurately match your requirement:

```js
/\bbg-(\w+-)+\d0{2}\b/g
```

- `\b` word boundary (start of word)
- `bg-` literal match for characters `b`, `g`, and `-` (hyphen)
- `(   )+` one or more:

  - `\w+` one or more word-characters

    - same as `[0-9A-Za-z]+`
  - `-` hyphen (literal match)
- `\d` one digit

  - same as `[0-9]`
- `0{2}` number zero `0` (literal match)

  - `{2}` two times
  - same as `00`
- `\b` word boundary (end of word)
- `g` flag - global search (find all  matches)

[Pattern Diagram](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cbbg-%28%5Cw%2B-%29%2B%5Cd0%7B2%7D%5Cb%2Fg):

[image: regex pattern diagram]

Comment: Thanks also to you.. This explanation is very helpful. I'll try to adapt it to another research. Thank you 